Why is my battery indicator suddenly changing from full to almost empty?
A couple of months ago my battery indicator started acting. It suddenly goes from full to almost empty showing the low battery warning and switching to power saver mode. For instance it shows 7% remaining but at the same shows more than 6 hours of power remaining. I then power off and on and it works again. It usually happens few times a week getting worse. My system is a 2017 mac book air with Ubuntu 22.04 installed. Is there a sort of reset for the battery level indicator?

The data shown about batteries comes from the BIOS. If this is the original battery do a healthcheck; it is likely broken (see for instance https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-status.html.en )

I replaced the battery beginning of the year. The battery is good. The problem is with the battery indicator.
